# How to use stye attribute in custom block markup?

Tags: 8, input-formats

I'm developing a custom block in Drupal 8. In my `build()` method I've got:

```
$progress_markup = array(
  '#theme' => 'progress_bar',
  '#percentage' => $registration_percentage,
  '#message' => array('#markup' => $registration_node_count . ' of ' . $this->configuration['capacity']),
);
$markup = \Drupal::theme()->render('progress_bar', $progress_markup);
```

This generates the following HTML:

```
<div class="progress" data-drupal-progress>
  <div class="progress__track"><div class="progress__bar" style="width: %"></div></div>
  <div class="progress__percentage">%</div>
  <div class="progress__description">30 of 120</div>
</div>
```

However, when the block renders on the page, the `style` attribute has been removed. Here's the relevant [D8 issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2549077).

What I don't understand is: if I create a custom block and use Full HTML, and paste in the generated markup that contains the `style` attribute, Drupal 8 will happily render it. But when I generate this markup in the `build()` method, it gets removed.

Is there a way to specify, in the block plugin definition, that the `build()` method should not filter out any HTML? Any other thoughts on how ot get around this issue?

Comment: The build method should return a render array and not markup.

Comment: @Eyal thanks, but that doesn't really answer my question. If I just returned the `$progress_markup` variable in the `build()` method, the `style` attribute is still filtered out.

Comment: How are you trying to pass the style attribute?

Comment: @Eyal not sure if this helps, but here is the code https://github.com/durhamatletico/durhamatletico-cms/blob/master/modules/custom/durhamatletico_registration/src/Plugin/Block/RegistrationCapacityBlock.php and the block is on the homepage of durhamatletico.com

Comment: Try to pass the render array without rendering it.

Comment: That's what I was saying in my second comment: that doesn't work. The style attribute is still sanitized.

Comment: Edit your answer and provide the way you tried to pass the style attribute.

Comment: I think it's already clear but if you have suggestions on how to improve the question, let me know!

Answer (score 5):

This is a working example of adding the style attribute to the render array of a block via the build() method.

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains Drupal\foo\Plugin\Block\FooBlock
 */


namespace Drupal\foo\Plugin\Block;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;


/**
 * @block(
 *   id = "foo",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Foo block")
 * )
 */
class FooBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * Builds and returns the renderable array for this block plugin.
   *
   * If a block should not be rendered because it has no content, then this
   * method must also ensure to return no content: it must then only return an
   * empty array, or an empty array with #cache set (with cacheability metadata
   * indicating the circumstances for it being empty).
   *
   * @return array
   *   A renderable array representing the content of the block.
   *
   * @see \Drupal\block\BlockViewBuilder
   */
  public function build() {
    return [
      'inside' => [
        '#type' => 'html_tag',
        '#tag' => 'div',
        '#value' => 'Hello world',
        '#attributes' => [
          'class' => ['some-class'],
          'style' => ['color:red']
        ]
      ]
    ];
  }
}
```

[image: Working example]

Comment: This is nice but how to you send attributes to the wrapper DIV of a custom block.  I know it can be done with preprocess hooks but I was wondering if it can be done from here ...

Comment: Try `#wrapper_attributes`

Comment: thanks for trying but it does not work ... I will try to open up a proper question ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a `#attributes` property in your render array, but at the **root** of the render array. Here we add `block-class` class to the block :

```
class FooBlock extends BlockBase {

  public function build() {
    return [
      'inside' => [
        '#type' => 'html_tag',
        '#tag' => 'div',
        '#value' => 'Hello world',
        '#attributes' => [
          'class' => ['inside-class'],
        ]
      ],
      '#attributes' => [
        'class' => ['block-class']
      ]
    ];
  }
}
```